# How to get accuracy for all the predicted class labels

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How can I find the overall accuracy of the outputs that we got by running a decision tree algorithm.I am able to get the top five class labels for the active user input but I am getting the accuracy for the X_train and Y_train dataset using accuracy_score().Suppose I am getting five top recommendation . I wish to get the accuracy for each class labels and with the help of these, the overall accuracy for the output.Please suggest some idea.

My python script is here:
here event is the different class labels

```
DTC= DecisionTreeClassifier()

DTC.fit(X_train_one_hot,y_train)
print("output from DTC:")
res=DTC.predict_proba(X_test_one_hot)
new=list(chain.from_iterable(res))
#Here I got the index value of top five probabilities
index=sorted(range(len(new)), key=lambda i: new[i], reverse=True)[:5]
for i in index:
    print(event[i])

Here is the sample code which i tried to get the accuracy for the predicted class labels: 
here index is the index for the top five probability of class label and event is the different class label. 
for i in index: 
    DTC.fit(X_train_one_hot,y_train) 
    y_pred=event[i]  
    AC=accuracy_score((event,y_pred)*100) 
    print(AC)
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far (code & results), otherwise your question is way too broad.

Comment: I have used the predict_proba() to get the probability of class labels then I retrieved the top 5 classes associated with these probabilities now  I want the accuracy for each of these classes.
I have edited my post with the sample code.

Comment: What is the shape of y_train?

Comment: the shape of y_train is-(21890,)

Comment: construct a y_hat(class) like that: y_hat(class) = 1 if desired class is in top 5 classes, else 0. Then compute the accuracy score of y_train to y_hat

Comment: I didn't get it. I got the top five classes I just need to check that what is the accuracy for each class.
Here is the sample code which i tried:
here index is the index for the top five probability of class label and event is the different class label.
for i in index:

    DTC.fit(X_train_one_hot,y_train)

    y_pred=event[i]
    print(type(y_pred))
    AC=accuracy_score((event,y_pred)*100)
    print(AC)

Comment: @Neha Please, do *not* use the comments space for posting code - edit & update your post if necessary!

Comment: Ok, so this is a multiclass task. Why do you need the accuracy only for top 5 classes? How to consider those samples which dont have that class as true target?

Comment: @Vivek I want the accuracy for the top 5 recommendation that I am getting with the help of predict_proba(). I am able to get the accuracy for the test data set but I want the seperate accuracy for the predicted recommendation which I got after passing the active user input.

Comment: @desertnaut I have updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a multi-class classification problem, you can calculate accuracy of the classifier by using the [`confusion_matrix`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html) function in Python.

To get overall accuracy, sum the values in the diagonal and divide the sum by the total number of samples.

Consider the following simple multi-class classification [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-confusion-matrix-py) using the IRIS dataset:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
class_names = iris.target_names

# Split the data into a training set and a test set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

# Run classifier, using a model that is too regularized (C too low) to see
# the impact on the results
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=0.01)
y_pred = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```

Now to calculate overall accuracy, use confusion matrix:

```
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_test)
acc = np.sum(conf_mat.diagonal()) / np.sum(conf_mat)
print('Overall accuracy: {} %'.format(acc*100))
```

Comment: y_pred = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test) here it will calculate the class label for the X_test but predict() will give me only one class label but I want more than one label that's why I have used predict_proba(). I have updated my post with the sample code that I am using for calculating the accuracy of the recommendation that I am getting. Can you plaese take a look at it

Comment: Why would you want more than one label for a given observation? `predict_proba()` gives you the probability of assigning a class label to a sample. Eventually based on the probabilities you choose one class label per sample.

Comment: yes predict_proba() will give the probability and with that probability I got the probability of top five labels and also the index of these associated labels by these index I find out the value of these labels. I need to provide the top five recommendation that's why I need more than one label for a give observation.

Comment: In order to calculate accuracy you need to use one label per observation. If you want to use more than one, you may look into top-1 or top-5 accuracy scores. See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156471/imagenet-what-is-top-1-and-top-5-error-rate) post for more details.